# Passing a reference to a function in PHP

Tags: php, yii

I saw some similar questions but none were exactly what I need.
I have the following classes:

```
abstract class A
{
    abstract function foo(); 

    public function callingD()
    {
         D::doSomething($this->foo());  //something like that
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    function foo()
    {
       //some code
    }
}

class C extends A
{
    function foo()
    {
       //some code
    }
}

class D
{
    public static function doSomething($fooImp)
    {
       //some code
    }
}
```

Now, what I want is to call `D::doSomething` from a function in class `A` and that one of the parameters for `doSomething` will be the implementation of `foo` in `A`'s current instance. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're merely asking for how to pass a [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php); the dance and song about abstract classes is pretty irrelevant:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract function foo(); 

    public function callingD() {
         D::doSomething([$this, 'foo']);
    }
}

class D {
    public static function doSomething(callable $fun) {
       $fun();
    }
}
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: If foo is an abstract method then what is the meaning by passing [$this, 'foo']?

Comment: In the class which will actually be instantiated, which ***can*** be instantiated, `foo` won't be abstract (because as long as `foo` is abstract the class cannot be instantiated). With `(new B)->callingD()`, `[$this, 'foo']` will refer to `B`'s implementation of `foo`, because `$this` will refer to an instance of `B`.

Comment: That's kind of the point of `abstract` classes and methods. You can as well write `$this->foo()` inside `callingD` and there'd be no question about calling an abstract method (I'd hope).

Comment: I'll try it, Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more question: How to call callingD() method of class A?

Comment: @Ravi You don't. It's an abstract class. You call `callingD` of an instance of one of `A`'s non-abstract children.

Comment: @deceze: Here B extends A and $obj = new B;
$obj->callingD(); By calling that way it will give Notice: Undefined variable: this.

Comment: @Ravi Wut? Err... no!?

Comment: @deceze: I am getting Notice. So no any Erorr no. I have used OP's code and just replace your callingD() method in Class A

Comment: @Ravi I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about: https://3v4l.org/V9kdG

Comment: @deceze: Now I am getting you. Thanks a lot for your link. Now I have clear concept. Great answer :-)